# JSON Array Literal to Object using JQ

Tags: json, jq

I am using an AWS CLI command with json output and it creates an array:

```
aws lambda list-functions --region us-east-2 --query 'Functions[?starts_with(FunctionName, `DEV`) == `true`].FunctionName' --output json
```

Which returns:

```
[
    "DEV-Lambda1-xxxx",
    "DEV-Lambda2-xxxx",
    "DEV-Lambda3-xxxx",
    "DEV-Lambda4-xxxx"
]
```

In order to properly use the output in my Terraform, I need it to be a JSON *object*. Here is a simplified example:

```
{
"lambda1": "DEV-Lambda1-xxxx",
"lambda2": "DEV-Lambda2-xxxx",
"lambda3": "DEV-Lambda3-xxxx",
"lambda4": "DEV-Lambda4-xxxx"
}
```

I would like to use `jq` 1.5 or greater. How do I transpose an array into an object?

I've only been able to make it this far:

```
map( { ("lambda"): . } ) | add
```

Which outputs only the last lambda:

```
{
  "lambda": "DEV-Lambda4-xxxx"
}
```

Comment: "JSON object." JSON is a string that most often gets parsed into a JavaScript object or on the server side an object with that signature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a range iteration over the array and form the desired k/v pair

```
jq '[ range(0; length) as $r | 
  { ( .[$r] | split("-")[1] | ascii_downcase) : .[$r] } ] | add'
```

[jqplay - demo(1)](https://jqplay.org/s/5OPUWklsSl)

or do a transposition of the array and form the k/v pair

```
jq --slurp 'transpose | 
  map( { ( .[] | split("-")[1] | ascii_downcase) : .[] } ) | add'
```

[jqplay - demo(2)](https://jqplay.org/s/DoTOlNiuhf)

Comment: Thanks. I was able to make this work for my specific application just by changing it a bit.

Comment: @wblakecannon: Do upvote the answer as well if it helped you!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be to use `to_entries | map(…) | from_entries`, or its shortcut `with_entries(…)`.

Then change the key based either on a static string and the numeric index:

```sh
jq 'with_entries(.key |= "lambda\(.+1)")'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/S_EGkWtk4A)

Or on the lower case version of the middle part of the value:

```sh
jq 'with_entries(.key = ((.value / "-")[1] | ascii_downcase))'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/7L5X7WPGQu)

```json
{
  "lambda1": "DEV-Lambda1-xxxx",
  "lambda2": "DEV-Lambda2-xxxx",
  "lambda3": "DEV-Lambda3-xxxx",
  "lambda4": "DEV-Lambda4-xxxx"
}
```